# Assume Half a Disjunctive Premise for "or elimination" Proof

Tags: coq

I think by this point I've read most if not all of the 81 questions tagged [coq](/questions/tagged/coq). Being very new to coq, I was unable to find an answer to this very simple question (which I'm fairly certain has not been asked on SO because of how basic it is).

I am working on a homework assignment, for which I need to use coq to prove:

- Given: P/Q. ~Q
- Prove: P

This is a simple enough proof for me to do on paper, but I can't seem to get coq to do this for me.

My strategy is to assume each of `P` and `Q`, to show `P` and therefore conclude that `P` must hold:

1. P / Q [Premise]
2. ~Q [Premise]

   1. P [Assumption]
   2. P [Copy Previous Line]

      ---
   3. Q [Assumption]
   4. ~Q [Copy Previous Line]
   5. [Contradiction]
   6. P [Contradiction Elimination]
3. P [Elimination of `\/`]

---

Given that this is how I would prove it on paper, I was able to come up with the following coq code to prove it in coq. Sadly my effort to assume `P`, `Q`, or `~P` don't come through:

```
Section Q5.

Variables P Q : Prop.
Hypothesis premise1 : P \/ Q.
Hypothesis premise2 : ~Q.

Goal P.
```

Here are my attempts for the next line, along with the errors they produce:

```
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Code       |                                Error                                |
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| assumption.     | Error: No such assumption.                                          |
| exact P.        | The term "P" has type "Prop" while it is expected to have type "P". |
| apply premise1. | Error: Impossible to unify "P \/ Q" with "P".                       |
| apply P.        | Error: Impossible to unify "Prop" with "P".                         |
+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'd appreciate any help with this since I've exhausted everything that I can think of at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your strategy well, but it seems right.

What you want to do is basically consider the two cases of the `P \/ Q` disjunction. This can be done via the tactic `destruct premise1.`, which will yield two goals, one in which `p: P`, and one in which `q: Q`. These two should be easy to prove.

For the reasons why your tactics failed:

```
P : Prop
Q : Prop
premise1 : P \/ Q
premise2 : ~ Q
______________________________________(1/1)
P
```

1. `assumption.` will not work because it just looks in your hypotheses for a term whose type is your current goal. There is no term at type `P` here.
2. `exact P.` will fail because the tactic `exact <term>.` is supposed to solve a goal `<type>` if `<term> : <type>`. Your goal is not `Prop`, right? :)
3. `apply premise1.` will fail because it only applies on a goal `P \/ Q`.
4. `apply P.` is basically the same as `exact P.` at that point.

---

Overall, you seem to have a (common) problem thinking apart terms and types. Remember that your goal is a type, which you try to prove by building a term. Your hypotheses are all of the form `<term> : <type>`, so whenever you use `exact <term>.` or `apply <term>.`, it's because the stuff on the right of the colon after `<term>` matches your goal, not the name on the left of the colon.

Comment: `destruct premise1` worked perfectly. Thank you. Would you be able to point me to a glossary of all coq commands and their functions? I think my basic problem is that I don't what commands exist

Comment: Adam Chlipala has a quick reference here: http://adam.chlipala.net/itp/tactic-reference.html and the Coq website has the list of all documented tactics here: http://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactic-index.html (but that website is down for the week-end due to maintenance).